# Farseer physics: Collision detection issues

Tags: box2d, game-physics, physics-engine, farseer

I have three rectangular blocks: ground block, blue block, hero block.
Ground is placed at the bottom of screen, blue block lay on ground block and hero block is falling down to blue block. I have listener which detects when hero is touched ground.
There are two situations:
1) When hero falls down from low height to blue block its ok listener notify that hero contacts only blue block.
2) When hero falls down from a bit higher height to blue block listener notify that hero touches ground !!! How to solve this issue ?

This is hero OnCollision listener:

```
bool heroBody_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, Contact contact)
{

  Texture2D textureB = (Texture2D)fixtureB.UserData;
  string textureBName = ((string)textureB.Tag).ToLower();

  if (textureBName == "ground")
  { 
    OnHeroTouchedGround();
    return true;
   }
   else if (textureBName.Contains("blue"))
   {       
     OnHeroTouchedBlueBlock();
     return true;
   }

   return true;
}


    public HeroState GetHeroState()
    {
        ContactEdge contactEdge = null;

        if (heroBody != null) contactEdge = heroBody.ContactList;

        while (contactEdge != null)
        {
            if (heroBody.LinearVelocity == Vector2.Zero)
            {
                Texture2D textureA = (Texture2D)contactEdge.Contact.FixtureA.UserData;
                string textureAName = ((string)textureA.Tag).ToLower();
                Texture2D textureB = (Texture2D)contactEdge.Contact.FixtureB.UserData;
                string textureBName = ((string)textureB.Tag).ToLower();

                if (textureAName == "ground" || textureBName == "ground")
                    return HeroState.OnGroud;
                 else if (textureAName.Contains("blue") ||    textureBName.Contains("blue"))
                    return HeroState.OnHome;
            }

            contactEdge = contactEdge.Next;
        }

        return HeroState.Playing;
    }
```

Comment: Is the blue block very thin? Is it light while the hero is heavy? Is it possible that the hero block is moving fast enough that he can penetrate into both blocks for a short time?

Comment: Hero block has size of 60x60px,  blue block has height of 20px. Visually hero is not falling down fast and penetrate through blue block. Note: sim units to display is 1m = 100px. Maybe, i have to play with some farseer engine parameters but what are they exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's different depending on the height dropped from suggests that the hero is penetrating right through the blue block to touch the ground. Try setting the hero block to be a bullet body, if the problem is fixed then this was indeed the case. You could also experiment with the height of the blue block to see how it affects things.

I recommend using debug draw to check that what you are seeing is really what's happening in the physics engine.

Comment: Tried to set hero as bullet body but problem is not fixed.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you are not checking fixtureA at all in that code. There is no guarantee that fixtureA is the hero, so really the sub function there should be called "OnSomethingTouchedGround" :) However if you are already checking that fixtureA is the hero before this function is called, it should be ok.

Comment: I checked fixtureA is always hero because of  heroBody.OnCollision +=  heroBody_OnCollision; so i removed unnecessary checks. By the way when hero speed becomes zero he has 2 contacts : Blue block which is true and unfortunately orange block :(.

Comment: Full Actual collision check function GetHeroState();

Comment: I added checks for FixtureA to heroBody_OnCollision(). And it shows that no any collision with ground !!! Its very good ! But there is still a problem i want to check what blocks does hero contact. When hero speed is Zero i get contact list and there is 3 contacts: ground with blue, blue with hero and ground with hero. Third item kills me ...

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve the issue:
1) I plugged Farseer project to my solution
2) in Settings.cs found line 
     public const float AABBExtension = 0.1f;
3) Changed value to '0.01f'. And it works !!!

Comment: okay, I think I see what's happening now. Are you not using the BeginContact callback? BeginContact will be called when two fixtures begin to touch. I'm not familiar with a 'contact list', but it sounds like it contains contacts for fixtures which only have AABBs overlapping - this does not mean the fixtures themselves are actually overlapping, but you can check if they are with IsTouching().

Comment: Where is BeginContact and how to use it? Did you mean for ex. heroBody.FixtureList[0].BeforeCollision = heroBody_OnCollision; ?

Comment: But now i use IsTouching() for contact and it works , no need anymore to change AABBExtension ! That it is i was searching for! Big thanks !